# Pseudo-random generators and pitfalls

Tags: randomness, pseudo-random-generator, entropy

I've read the Chapter "Randomness" from the *Serious Cryptography* book and it raised some questions. Namely:

It is written that *Mersenne Twister* is proved to be cryptographically irreliable. And that is it used by some languages, especially by Python. I have seen a lot of project with different languages when secure random stuff (like keys, token, sessions and so on) were generated just by taking random bits from a standard library.

I have not seen a situation when someone takes care of entropy level.

How to know that generating (pseudo) random keys is secure? Especially, I don't see implementation of pseudorandom generator that return error (for example when entropy is not sufficient). Could tell me something about my doubts and recommend me any book/article that covers that subject more specifically.

Comment: You have to make sure you are taking from a _secure_ source if you want unguessable values (e.g. for a key). How that is done depends entirely on the language.

Comment: The GPG program (https://github.com/gpg/gnupg) takes care of entropy in the way you allude to, the user is required to wait/generate 'random noise' until the program has determined a sufficient amount of entropy is available for key generation.

Answer (score 1):

First, If the source isn’t explicitly labeled as “secure” or “crypto” in its name, you must assume it is *insecure*.

For example, in C#, the `System.Random` is insecure while `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator` is obviously intended to be a secure RNG.

Second, you’ll need to actually do some research to ensure that it is, in fact, going to be a secure RNG in the version you are using, and in the target deployment environment. Will you have an entropy source when it is deployed?

Most languages let you access the operating system’s secure RNG in some way; these should be preferred over any user-space generators to ensure `fork()`-safety. User-space RNGs are also [far more likely to have bugs](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=random) or their state compromised by bugs in user-space applications, which history shows are innumerable.

For example, Pythons `os.urandom()` doesn’t mention security in its name, but it does call the operating systems secure RNG directly (`/dev/urandom` on Linux and `CryptGenRandom` on Windows). When you use the OS generator you also don’t need to evaluate the security of a particular language’s generator user-space algorithm choices or implementation quality.

The OS generator on any recent mainstream OS can be trusted, unless you’re deploying into an environment with no entropy source (such as an embedded Linux device with no user inputs and no hardware RNG).

Comment: _"The OS generator on any recent mainstream OS can be trusted"_ is wildly overoptimistic. Here's a recent serious [bug](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-1108), and history is badly repeating itself on that one. The software of the OS could be rigged. The hardware could be rigged (e.g. with a JTAG probe). VMs are a thing...

Comment: @fgrieu What is one supposed to do in that situation to solve the problem?

Comment: @Ella Rose: Try hard to know your hardware, and be as sure as possible that it runs the software you think it runs. For critical things, mix entropy sources using something carefully reviewed that demonstrably is secure if any of its source is secure. Do include the OS (e.g. `/dev/urandom` or `CryptGenRandom`) as one of these. Ideas for the rest include `clock_gettime` or `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`, hash of `wmic process` output, and values of `RTDSC` or `QueryPerformanceCounter` before and after gathering that. A comment is too small for all my tricks, and I'm reluctant to reveal them all.

Comment: @fgrieu If you can't trust the OS you're screwed anyway.  "know your hardware" - how do you think you're communicating with that hardware?  The OS.  There are multiple levels of paranoia, however most applications do not have to be resistant when the OS has been compromised.

Comment: @Swashbuckler: "If you can't trust the OS you're screwed anyway" is a little too radical. We positively must make sure that the OS is not intentionally altered. We need to trust that it is not intentionally backdoored. But as far as randomness goes (e.g. for key generation), we need not trust the OS blindly. We can bring entropy from multiple sources, and live with a bug in the OS's RNG, like so many have crept in linux. We just need the fact that the XOR of multiple independent random sources is at least as good as the best one.

Comment: @fgrieu a user-space CSPRNG is not going to save you from a backdoored OS or hardware. It is, however, a lot of added complexity that is easy to screw up. Critical Bugs in user space RNGs far outnumber those in kernel RNGs if you look at CVEs. User-space RNGs are still subject to all the dangers of early boot, little physical entropy, and VM cloning. But they add the more serious dangers of forking and access control to the state. How is that good for security?

Comment: @EllaRose Build your own TRNG as I keep saying.  It's the only way to be certain. It's not that hard.

Comment: @rmalayter: For all the reasons that you state, we should fear a backdoored hardware, OS, or software, and we should not use user-space-only RNGs. I'm still favorable to combining entropy from multiple sources including the OS, with user-space code so simple that we can be sure it is correct, when it comes to generating important secrets. I'm thinking e.g. of key generation ceremonies, where the OS and software is used by and available for analysis to multiple parties, and there must be a convincing argument their secrets are independent.

Comment: @fgrieu "we need not trust the OS blindly. We can bring entropy from multiple sources"  What entropy source can you trust if the OS is compromised?

Comment: @Swashbuckler: is the OS is compromized, we are toast anyway. But if the OS only has an accidentally flawed RNG (which has happened times and times) then adding in other sources of entropy can save the day.